# Error with a simple javascript prototype

Tags: javascript, oop, websocket

Can someone help me?

I tried this code :

```
function Network(ip, port){
    this.Socket = new WebSocket('ws://' + ip + ':' + port);
    this.Socket.onopen = function(){
        console.log('connected');
        this.send('test');
    }
}
Network.prototype = {

    sendMessage : function(data){
        this.Socket.send(data);
        alert(data);
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    window.network = new Network('localhost', '8887');
    window.network.sendMessage("Hello, world!");
});
```

But when I launch it I get a " Uncaught Error: InvalidStateError: DOM Exception 11 ". I googled more than 1 hour and didn't find something...

On my server I get :

```
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%0 entered the room!
org.java_websocket.WebSocketImpl@584fce71: test
```

So, the problem is in the sendMessage function..
Can someone help me ? thanks ! :)

Answer (score 0):

WebSocket is a async function. please wait it connected success to sendmessage.

Comment: I don't think the problem come from that, because the "Test" has been sucessfully sent to my server

Comment: it's output the "connected"?

Comment: The send(data) method transmits data using the connection. If the readyState attribute is CONNECTING, it must throw an InvalidStateError exception.

Comment: The output is : Uncaught Error: InvalidStateError: DOM Exception 11 test.html:21
connected
You're right, it seems that it is trying to send the message before being connected, how can I fix that?

Comment: you can send it in onopen function.

Comment: if (this.Socket.readyState === 1) {
      this.Socket.send('some thing');
}